# Close socket connection

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I'm using sockets to connect to my server.
The problem is:
The server accepts a connection.
Close it and wait again.

I use 2 sockets:
1 for message and another to transfer the data itself.
How can i close the socket connection.

I use shutdown(socket, 2); and close(socket);

I tried to add the reuseaddr:

```
int i=1;
setsockopt(sockDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &i, sizeof(int));
```

Thanks

Comment: usually there is a name(reference) for each socket.

Comment: How can i get that, how i close the socket connection?

Comment: -1 your question is too vague.  Which socket do you want to close - the message socket or the transfer socket?  What have you tried so far, and what exactly has not worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just added a sleep(1) and now its ok.
Remy Lebeau, i wanted to close any socked, it seems when i close the socket i need to wait a very little time, that was the problem.

Thanks ppl

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem description, but you almost certainly shouldn't need to sleep after/before closing a socket. It makes no sense. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: Agree with @Celada, sleep is not necessary to close a socket.

Comment: I agree too, if i dont do even a little sleep it seems the socket dont close, it seems the system needs some time to do it. On linux its ok, but on mac os x dont work without sleep.

Comment: I don't think add sleep() would be a good idea... your code might be easily broken in real time.